# Hosting Flask App on Apache with External Templates Folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, flask, jinja2

I am trying to deploy a very basic flask app to apache. The app has the following file structure:

```
var
  www
    myapp
      myapp.py
      myapp.wsgi
```

The templates folder is in an external directory that has the following structure:

```
data
  templates
    index.html
```

Because the templates folder is in another directory, the code for myapp.py looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from pathlib import Path

templates_dir = Path(r'/data/templates')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=templates_dir)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I also have a myapp.wsgi file to interface with mod_wsgi and apache that looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myapp')

from myapp import app as application
```

There is also an apache configuration file in /etc/httpd/conf.d called myapp.conf that looks like this:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=apache group=apache
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory "/var/www/myapp">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run this application using the flask development server with `flask --app myapp run --host=0.0.0.0`, everything works fine.

However, when I try to deploy the application with apache and navigate to my ip address, I get an internal server error. The apache error.log file shows the following:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
  raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

I have tried adding this to the myapp.conf file which did not help:

```
<Directory "/data/templates">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What do I need to do so that apache can access the external templates folder?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by doing: `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/data/templates(/.*)?"`
and then:
`restorecon -R /data/templates`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).